# findstr exclude some subdirectories

Tags: cmd, findstr

I am using findstr /s to find what I am looking for. How can I exclude some sub directories?
For example, Main Direc -> Sub folder 1, Sub folder 2, Sub folder 3, Sub folder 4

```
findstr /s /i /C:"SWG_DD_STANDARD_DATE" *.* > E:\Private\ORA_APPS_DEV\WO_WIP\ONE_OFF\NARAIN_ALL\Search\search.txt
```

How can I exclude sub folder 2 from my search?

Comment: [What does your current code look like?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Please post it here so that we can see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Why do you need to see the code? Was my explanation not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the list of folders and exclude the non required one

```dos
(for /d %%a in (*) do if /i not "%%a"=="subfolder2" (
    findstr /s /i /C:"SWG_DD_STANDARD_DATE" "%%a\*"
)) > E:\Private\ORA_APPS_DEV\WO_WIP\ONE_OFF\NARAIN_ALL\Search\search.txt
```

Or, if the only need is to exclude the folder from the output, you can filter it

```dos
findstr /s /i /C:"SWG_DD_STANDARD_DATE" * | findstr /v /b /i /c:"subfolder2" >  E:\Private\ORA_APPS_DEV\WO_WIP\ONE_OFF\NARAIN_ALL\Search\search.txt
```